# Python Tkinter Scrollbar Not Working

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a new program in Python 3 with tkinter. I'm trying to add a scrollbar to the whole window, but it isn't working. Right now I'm just trying to make the window 1000 pixels tall (will be set later in the program) and use the a vertical scrollbar to access the parts not seen on screen. I've read multiple other threads trying to figure it out and have attempted. Could someone tell how to get it to work and what I did wrong. No error is displayed, but also no scrollbar is displayed. Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
class MusicPlayer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.tk.title("Bass Blaster")
        self.screen_width, self.screen_height = self.tk.winfo_screenwidth(), self.tk.winfo_screenheight()
        self.frame = Frame(self.tk, width=self.screen_width, height=self.screen_height)
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame, bg="#585858", width=self.screen_width, height=self.screen_height, scrollregion=(0, 0, self.screen_width, 1000))
        vbar = Scrollbar(self.frame, orient=VERTICAL)
        vbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        vbar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.config(width=self.screen_width, height=self.screen_height)
        self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
        self.canvas.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)
        self.tk.update()

bass_blaster = MusicPlayer()
bass_blaster.tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't know how Tkinter works under the hood, but your `vbar` variable is locale to the `__init__` method, then when you leave it, `vbar` is destroyed, unless you have a reference to it. Tkinter might not save your reference as a child, and your Scrollbar is destroyed when you leave the `__init__` method. Try to make it as class member. (you should also make your class `MusicPlayer` inherits from `Tk`)

Comment: @romain-aga I changed vbar to self.vbar, thinking that was it, but it made no difference. Will try inheriting Tk

Comment: Seems like the height of the canvas is greater than 1000.  Try set the canvas height to less than 1000.

Comment: I also have the scrollbar when I execute it

Comment: @acw1668, I think, you should make an answer, it worked for me, it may work too for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The scroll bar was there the whole time, the problem was that I made the canvas width the screen's size and the scroll bar was adding onto the width, therefore going off the screen. I just had to make the width a little less.